# Date to UTC not taking into account daylight savings

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone, dst, nodatime

I am using a date (1/1/2018 11:30 AM) with timezone (Eastern Standard Time) and converting it to a UTC date (2018-01-01T16:30:00Z).  The original date is really Eastern Daylights Savings, so when developers do a conversion with the UTC, they get 12:30 PM instead of 11:30 AM.  If I do 8/26/2018 11:30 AM, it works fine.  My time zones are in the .NET Windows formats.

Is there a way with my method below to get the correct UTC that has the daylight savings from the timezone that is Standard with NodaTime?

```
2018-01-01T16:30:00Z = Helper.GetUtcTimeZone("1/1/2018 11:30 AM", "Eastern Standard Time").ToString();
```

**Method**

```
public static Instant GetUtcTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, string timeZone)
{
    var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone ?? TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName);

    if (timeZoneInfo != null)
    {
        if (dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        {
            dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZoneInfo);
        }
    }

    return Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep using `TimeZoneInfo`, just use it directly.  No need for all the extra logic you've added.

```
public static Instant GetUtcTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, string timeZone)
{
    TimeZoneInfo timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
    DateTime utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZoneInfo);
    return Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDateTime);
}
```

Though really, once you are using NodaTime, there's no reason for that.  Just use its built-in functionality:

```
public static Instant GetUtcTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, string timeZone)
{
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl[timeZone];
    return ldt.InZoneLeniently(tz).ToInstant();
}
```

One important note: You had a fall-back to `TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName`.  That's not safe - as the `StandardName` fields are *localized*, and don't always match the names of the identifiers even in English.  Use `Id` instead of `StandardName` if you are expecting an identifier.  In NodaTime, you can use `DateTimeZoneProviders.Bcl.GetSystemDefault()`.

Comment: Also note the first date you gave is in *January*, so it can't be in EDT.